# Using AnnotatorJS on Dynamic content in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, annotations, annotatorjs

I am working on implementing the AnnotatorJS library in a rails applications where an Admin user has the ability to Annotate a piece of content, and a lower-level user has the ability to edit that content based on the annotations. I am able to load, create, update, and delete these annotations as the Admin user, however; I am running to a problem when the lower-level user makes edits to that piece of content. It looks like the annotator only uses the range to determine where an annotation is visible. For example:

Imagine that the bolded text is the annotation, the content reads:

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus eget urna sit amet facilisis. Aenean luctus odio vitae sapien
>   malesuada, convallis vehicula ligula egestas. Ut quis neque eget mi
>   hendrerit interdum. Vivamus a accumsan nisi, ac lacinia urna. Duis
>   hendrerit justo a lacinia sodales. Phasellus eu maximus elit.

If the user goes in and removes a word or deletes the phrase to follow the instructions of the annotation's comment, the highlighted annotation will move down string and will look similar to this:

> **Consectetur adipiscing eli**t. Sed faucibus eget urna sit amet facilisis. Aenean luctus odio vitae sapien malesuada, convallis
>   vehicula ligula egestas. Ut quis neque eget mi hendrerit interdum.
>   Vivamus a accumsan nisi, ac lacinia urna. Duis hendrerit justo a
>   lacinia sodales. Phasellus eu maximus elit.

Ideally, I would want the annotation to go away since I have made edits to that area of the text.

For more reference, here is how my rails models are structured

```
# Table name: annotations
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  version    :string
#  text       :text
#  quote      :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime

# Table name: annotation_ranges
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  annotation_id       :integer
#  start               :string
#  end                 :string
#  start_offset        :integer
#  end_offset          :integer
#  created_at          :datetime
#  updated_at          :datetime
```

JS that I am using to load annotations, I am just loading them through html data attributes, which are defined in the controller:

```
var annotation;

annotation = $('#annotations-body').annotator({
  readOnly: true
});

annotation.annotator('loadAnnotations', $('annotations-body').data('annotations'));
```

If anyone has figure out a way to only display annotations where the text in the ranges are equal to the quote that is stored. I would really appreciate some insight. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution for the same?

Comment: Same here, wondering if you nailed this issue